# Is there a more efficient way to fetch data from an API using axios? (React.js & node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

In this implementation, the code runs and achieves the purpose of what I am trying to do — use axios to fetch the dummy API at https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, then display it on the screen. However, I feel my code could be refactored to become more efficient. Currently, I have four useState constants (one for each property in the object), which are set/updated upon fetching. I tried to consolidate the `CurrentFetch` `CurrentFetch2` `CurrentFetch3` `CurrentFetch4` constants into a single `useState({})`object, but React was giving me errors for using objects here. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [fetchCount, setFetchCount] = useState(1);
  const [currentFetch, setCurrentFetch] = useState([]);
  const [currentFetch2, setCurrentFetch2] = useState([]);
  const [currentFetch3, setCurrentFetch3] = useState([]);
  const [currentFetch4, setCurrentFetch4] = useState([]);


  const HandleFetchApi = async () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${fetchCount}`)
      .then((response) => {
        let data = response.data;
        setCurrentFetch(data.userId);
        setCurrentFetch2(data.id);
        setCurrentFetch3(data.title);
        setCurrentFetch4(data.completed);
        setFetchCount(fetchCount + 1);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing API Fetch from Dummy Api</h1>
      <button onClick={HandleFetchApi}>
        Click to fetch record #{fetchCount}
      </button>
      <h2>user id: {currentFetch}</h2>
      <h2>id: {currentFetch2}</h2>
      <h2>title: {currentFetch3}</h2>
      <h2>completed: {currentFetch4.toString()}</h2>
      <br />

      <h5>from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/</h5>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: That looks like the code that works; you need to show your attempt at refactoring it. (`setTodo(response.data);` is all you need)

Comment: What errors were you getting when using a single object?

Comment: When I tried to `setCurrentFetch(data)`
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: You need to use `<h2>user id: {currentFetch.id}</h2>` then, you were trying to do exactly what the error says: render a non-React object. Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-dawn-66s6k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Also, the `<h2>completed: {currentFetch.completed?.toString()}</h2>` was super helpful. What does the `?.` mean in English semantics? @ChrisG

Comment: It means "don't crash with a null pointer error if `currentFetch.completed` is `undefined` but evaluate to `null`, otherwise call `.toString()` on it

Comment: No problem, but please always [google the error first](https://www.google.com/search?q=next+js+objects+are+not+valid+as+a+react+child+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Better version:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [fetchCount, setFetchCount] = useState(1);
  const [currentFetch, setCurrentFetch] = useState({
    userId: '',
    id: '',
    title: '',
    completed: ''
  });


  const HandleFetchApi = async () => {
    axios
      .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${fetchCount}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const { userId, id, title, completed } = response.data;
        setCurrentFetch({...currentFetch, ...{userId, id, title, completed}});
        setFetchCount(fetchCount + 1);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Testing API Fetch from Dummy Api</h1>
      <button onClick={HandleFetchApi}>
        Click to fetch record #{fetchCount}
      </button>
      <h2>user id: {currentFetch.userId}</h2>
      <h2>id: {currentFetch.id}</h2>
      <h2>title: {currentFetch.title}</h2>
      <h2>completed: {currentFetch.completed.toString()}</h2>
      <br />

      <h5>from: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/</h5>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you! This was the approach I was looking for! Don't forget to `setFetchCount(fetchCount + 1);` :)

Comment: Happy to hear. My pleasure :) Please mark as accepted this answer as this helps you.

Comment: Or just `setCurrentFetch({ ...currentFetch, ...response.data })`

Comment: Yeah i see. Updated my answer. Anyway, yes you could also do this `...response.data`  way but not recommended because good practice is to extract only the things we need. Otherwise unnecessary props will be added into `currentFetch`. Hope you understand buddy.